How to treat extended ASCII chars using lex?
I am trying to treat extended ascii characters with lex, e.g., àÀ.
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

DIGIT           [0-9]
ALPHA_CHAR      [A-Za-z]
EXTENDED        [àÀ]

CHAR             {ALPHA_CHAR}|{DIGIT}|{EXTENDED}
CHARS            ({CHAR})+

%%
{CHARS}    { printf("CHARS: %s\n", yytext); }
.          { printf("Unknown character: %s\n", yytext); }
%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}

When I am giving as input àÀ, my code prints Ã Ã€, as à is encoded 16 UTF8 bits 0xC3 = Ã and 0xA0 = NBSP, and so is À: 0xC3 = Ã and 0x80 = €.
What I could do is if I detect 0xC3, expect for a second byte, and add an appropriate offset to this character, to get the ASCII equivalent.
The offset would be = 0xC0 - 0x80, as 0xC0 is À is 0xC0 in ASCII, and 0xC380 in hex.
But I find this idea kind of dirty.
Any better ideas to handle this issue?

@tripleee in the topic you are mentionning, the user doesn't need to transform the different UTF8 bytes, into one single single byte. I have no issues characters like à or À, but treating them is one. Or I am not understanding...

The solution to use (á|À) instead of a character class should work for your case as well, I would assume.

@tripleee as I said, my issue is not about detecting extended ascii chars, I can handle this. But I kind of find dirty the transformation of UTF8 encoded chars to ASCII chars, and I was looking for cleaner solution.

The symptoms appear to indicate that your display is not set up to handle UTF-8 correctly.

I am displaying the chars for debug purpose, but in fact, I want my input character to be stored as a single byte in my compiled result file.

That doesn't make much sense; then you can only use ASCII plus 128 other characters. Back to the Latin-1 days.

... Though that also suggests a solution if that's really what you want; map the input to Latin-1 (or perhaps some bespoke 8-bit encoding of your own if you need to support characters which are not in Latin-1) and then process it.

@tony_merguez Bytes C3 A0 C3 80 is the correct UTF-8 encoded form of àÀ. Ã Ã€ is what you get when you display those bytes as ANSI, such as Latin-1, instead of as UTF-8.  This is not a code issue, the code is behaving correctly.  It is actually a terminal display issue. You need to configure your terminal to display UTF-8 properly.
